# how to fix: mongoose giving validation error on alternate doc.save() execution with same doc

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been trying to save a document with a username and a token in a mongodb database using mongoose. Whenever client makes a request to the server, the token is updated and saved in the database. To update the document I'm querying the collection with username(as it's unique), and then update the returned document's(say doc) token field and then calling the doc.save(). The problem is doc.save() gives me username validation error alternately(i.e. works on 1st and 3rd attempt, and so on...) but fails on 2nd attempt, 4th attempt and so on.

If I remove username validation constraint then the code works, however for apparent reasons, I can not remove the validation constraint.

users-model.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let user = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        match: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/g,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        match: /.{8,}/g,
        required: true,
    },
    token: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

getData.js

```
   module.exports = async function putData(database, model, query, fields, queryType='one'){
    let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const connectionURL = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${database}`;
    return mongoose.connect(connectionURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    }).then(()=>{
        return model.init();
    }).then(async ()=>{
        let res;
        switch(queryType){
            case 'one':
                res = await model.findOne(query).select(fields).exec();
                break;
            case 'all':
                res = await model.find(query).select(fields).exec();
        }
        return res;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

putData.js

```
   module.exports = async function putData(database, model, data, save=false){
    let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const connectionURL = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${database}`;
    console.log(connectionURL);
    return mongoose.connect(connectionURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    }).then(()=>{
        // console.log('successfull connection!', mongoose.connection.db.databaseName);
        return model.init();
    }).then(async ()=>{
        if(save){
            console.log('Saving data.....')
            // console.log(mongoose.connection.db.databaseName);
            let prom = await data.save();
            await mongoose.disconnect();
            return prom;
        }
        else{
            console.log('Creating the document....');
            // console.log(mongoose.connection.db.databaseName);
            let doc = new model(data);
            let prom = await doc.save();
            await mongoose.disconnect();
            return prom;
        }
    })
}
```

utils.js

```
let user = require('../models/users-model');
let putData = require('../putData');
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
let getData = require('../getData');

function update_token(username, token, callbackfn){
    getData('users', user, {
        username: username,
        token: token
    }, 'username token').then((userData)=>{
        console.log('Updating token....');
        if(userData && userData.token){
            bcrypt.hash(JSON.stringify(userData), 5).then((hash)=>{
                userData.token = hash;
                return putData('users', user, userData, true);
            }).then((data)=>{
                callbackfn(null, data);
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log('Cann\'t update the token');
                console.log(err);
                callbackfn(err, null);
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log('Invalid token');
            callbackfn(new Error('Invalid token'), null);
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        callbackfn(err, null);
    })
}

module.exports = {
    update_token: update_token
}
```

server.js

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let usersRouter = require('./routers/users');
let tourMakerRouter = require('./routers/tour-maker');
let bodyparser = require('body-parser');
let utils = require('./utils/utils');
let getData = require('./getData');
let user = require('./models/users-model');
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8000;

let jsonencodedparser = bodyparser.json();

app.post('/', jsonencodedparser, (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Request received!');
    utils.update_token(req.body.username, req.body.token, (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            if(err.message === 'Invalid token'){
                res.status(400).end();
            }
            res.status(500).end();
        }
        else{
            res.json({
                token: data.token,
                username: data.username
            });
        }
    })
})

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/tour-maker', tourMakerRouter);

app.listen(port, host, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
})
```

First Request:

`Request received!
{ _id: 5cdadbdfeeb7c02610b14f1a,
  username: 'user1',
  token: '$2b$05$oHkFuyW532Yq6p2o04TumeAON8SBtIL/lZ.Kty1gX2lqHqnMEI/Pa' }
Username is,  user1`

Second Request:

`Request received!
{ _id: 5cdadbdfeeb7c02610b14f1a,
  username: 'user1',
  token: '$2b$05$gaS5U4kRiVqCShKbiZe/t.LTUBTh5H7AAE7p2MXIUW65xezbPslG2' }
Username is,  user1
{ ValidationError: user validation failed: username: Path`username`is invalid (user1).
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (util.js:430:38)
    at inspect (util.js:324:10)
    at format (util.js:191:12)
    at Console.log (console.js:130:21)
    at utils.update_token (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/server/server.js:18:21)
    at bcrypt.hash.then.then.catch (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/server/utils/utils.js:20:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  errors: 
   { username: 
      { ValidatorError: Path`username`is invalid (user1).
    at new ValidatorError (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
    at validate (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:978:13)
    at /home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1031:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:987:14)
    at /home/arpit/Study/Projects/tour-maker/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2101:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
        message: 'Path`username`is invalid (user1).',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'regexp',
        path: 'username',
        value: 'user1',
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'user validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }`

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but have you tried checking the request every time to see what you're actually sending as the username?   There could be some validation issues for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, I'm logging the username every time I modify the document(see putData.js file)

Comment: you might want to delete this already. You have enough reputation to comment now :)